# Loading test file only works if using ClassLoader

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, java-8

I have a multimodule project.  I am using IntelliJ and have marked src/test/resources as a test resource directory.  I've placed abc.txt in that directory.

What's the reason why the first line executes for me, but the second doesn't, but works for others?

```
// this returns a stream
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt"));
// this returns null
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt"));
```

I found these suggestions after reading the first few hits in Google for loading test files.  I don't know what are the details that allow the second to work for some people but not me.

I found a few hints about ClassLoader not working in some corner cases.  Will this fail as soon as I push it up to Jenkins?

Comment: Could you share the code where you call this class from and how you execute the above code? Also, the classloader resolved when doing `this.getClass().getRes..` must be different in your case is what I would think about.

Comment: its the first test in the class.  There's only two lines in the test method.  I always have trouble with this kind of thing, so I went straight to this problem first.

Comment: have you tried `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/abc.txt")` ?

Comment: I thought I had tried every permutation, but it appears that `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/abc.txt")` works

Comment: see the documentation of the [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) which is use the relative path of the resources if it is not start with `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Every class has a ClassLoader defined for loading the class. In the context in question the only difference there is that with [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) as  in :

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt"));
```

*If* the object was loaded by the ***bootstrap class loader***, the method delegates to [`ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) which then uses the search path used to load classes to lookup for the resource.

Before delegation to any of the class loader, *an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name* within the method `Class.getResourceAsStream` using this algorithm:

- If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
- Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
  modified_package_name/name

  Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

In your case, the latter becomes true and hence it's not able to find the resource.